# Classified dataset for emotion recognition

Tags: opencv, csv, dataset, machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

I work with some research educational task and need dataset with classified facial emotions to train classifier. For example, gender classification is simple: I can create csv file, and mark any file with image as 0 or 1, according to gender. Something like this:

**.../../male.jpg:1**

**.../../female.jpg:0**
**...
...**

So, I need something similar, but for facial emotions classification. I found images dataset with keypoints, so I could cluster them by different emotions, but there'll be more accuracy if It is marked manually before. Maybe somebody has direct sourses, or links with information like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky because emotions are not uniquely characterized, even by humans.  But there are academics who have gone through the trouble to prepare the supervised data that you want, i.e. you could contact the authors below and ask about their data set:

"We introduce two large databases consisting of 750 000 and 1.2 million thumbnail-sized images, labeled with emotion-related keywords."  Solli and Lenz, Linkoping University, Norrkoping, Sweden.

Comment: Thanx for your answer. I found this dataset, its named as emodb, it is really cool stuff, but I need something more specific and not so large: files with faces, and any file(s), which describes emotions on the images, for example something similar as I described above.

Comment: @DmitryMikhaylenko I am having the same issue. Did you manage to find any image databases? please help me with one

Comment: Yes, we used dataset from kaggle competition (https://www.kaggle.com/c/facial-keypoints-detection/data) and optimized it for our purposes. We made features manually for all the images and than expanded it with the same images rotated different degrees

Answer (score 0):

Twitter is often a good place to start with sentiment analysis, because it provides in its advanced search the possilbity to filter for positive and negative tweets.

You can have a look here : https://twitter.com/search-advanced

If you want to go that way, you would need to write some code to use the twitter API as documented here :
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search

You can play with the API if you want here :
https://dev.twitter.com/console

- Choose "OAuth 1" for Authentication
- Set GET as method
- get positive twts at the following URL : [https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%3A)](https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%3A%29)
- get negative : [https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%3A(](https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%3a%28)

The results are returned as json.
It is usually enough to get very well started !

You will simply associate each tweet to the corresponding sentiment.

If you want a more "atomic" dataset, you can calculate a score for each word given how often it appears in the positive and negative classes, and normalize with a tf-idf approach.

Please note that if you want to build a more advanced classifier, you will need to handle "neutral" emotions as well, and this is not provided by twitter.

Comment: I didn't mentioned before: I need dataset with classified facial emotions by image with keypoints on face. It seems to me that the simplest way to create dataset like this is creating it manually. "Googling" didn't help me.

Comment: My bad, I skipped that part. In this case, you can still do the same, but see if you can isolate tweets with pictures, and add a face detector algorithm on top of that ! That may become quickly tricky though...